# Access 2003 report's calculated fields doesn't appear when exported to a xls file, but appears on a csv

Tags: excel, ms-access, reporting, ms-access-2003

I created several reports on Access 2003.

Some of their fields such as "Total spent time" are calculated based on other fields in the report that are being fetched from the database.
The TotalSpentTime textbox has the Control Source property set to "=Sum([NumberOfHours])".

The report looks alright when shown on screen, but whenever I try to export it to a xls file (be it in the Ms Excel 5-7 or Excel 2003 formats), the calculated fields aren't exported.

It's funny because the same calculated fields that I wanted to be in the xls file are there when I export it to csv.

I coudln't find anything that could help on the web.

Is there any way to get the calculated fields to be exported to a xls file?

Comment: How are you exporting the report?

Comment: With the report opened, I select File>Export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to change your query so that your sums are performed inside the query. It's my understanding that form-level sums are done during the formatting of the report and these sums are not performed when you export a report to Excel.

If you do some Google searching you'll see that this question is occasionally asked but I've been unable to find any authoritative answer from Microsoft or a Microsoft MVP.

Here's a similar question that came to the same conclusion:
http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/export-calculated-value-t1523613.html